# Unable to find layout for following design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

All buttons text are dynamically generated from the server. I have tried all the basic given layouts to form this design but unable to get desired result. Please help me , how can i solve this design implementation in android.

[image: Design which needs to be implemented.]

Comment: There is no Android View that can do this. There's no pattern other then 1-3 random buttons per row

Comment: try this: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout
or this: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2566

Comment: You just need 2 in one line and 3 in another line or according to space available there could be more like tags ?

Comment: @PreetikaKaur - Its not like that, it all depends upon the width of text, these are dynamic values which will be fetched from server. All the number of buttons to be generated will be dynamic. If there 4 small words all then it might accomodate in single row

Comment: try using staggered layout using recyclerview

Comment: ok sending tou simplest way in answers below

Comment: Use `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your layout.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tagviews"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
```

In your Java class

```
tagViews= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tagviews);
tagViews.removeAllViews();
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        LinearLayout childView;
        int remainingWidth, count = tagViews.getChildCount();
        if (count <= 0)
            tagViews.addView(ll);
        TextView tagText;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        int width = 0;
        WindowManager w = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager();
        Point size = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
        } else {
//            Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
//            width = d.getWidth();
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
             width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            //int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        }
        try {
            // you might have some array from where you want to set Tags
            for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(k);                
                final String name = obj.getString("name");
                for (int i = 0; i < tagViews.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    childView = (LinearLayout) tagViews.getChildAt(i);
                    tagText = new TextView(context);                    
                    tagText.setText(name);
                    tagText.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tagText.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
                    tagText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xee, 0xee, 0xee));
                    tagText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // for handling clicks on tags
                        }
                    });
                   // count = tagViews.getChildCount();
                    childView.measure(0, 0);
                    remainingWidth = width - childView.getMeasuredWidth();
                    //// Log.v("subcriptionAdapter", "remaining width=" + remainingWidth + " childview width= " + childView.getMeasuredWidth());
                    try {
                        if (remainingWidth > childView.getMeasuredWidth()) {
                            childView.addView(tagText);
                            childView.invalidate();
                            break;
                        } else if ((i == tagViews.getChildCount() - 1) && (remainingWidth < childView.getMeasuredWidth())) {
                            childView = new LinearLayout(context);
                            childView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                            childView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            childView.addView(tagText);
                            tagViews.addView(childView);
                            childView.invalidate();
                            break;
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        tagViews.invalidate();
```

It works for me Try it and let me know....

Comment: May I know what is holder here? Is it related to RecyvlerView Holder?

Comment: @AnkitGupta I have edited that actually I used this in my recyclerview holder adapter class so holder by mistake was not removed at few points while pasting code here in the above code. I have edited it now. You can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I marked this right as it was as desired, the only bug that i am facing is that few button have dissolved bottom sides. might be due to margin but tried that too. Will paste the pic again.

Comment: Happy to help.. Sure I would like to see

Answer (score 1):

The widget you need is AutoResize TextView

Try below class, it may help you

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AutoResizeTextView extends TextView {
private interface SizeTester {
    /**
     * 
     * @param suggestedSize
     *            Size of text to be tested
     * @param availableSpace
     *            available space in which text must fit
     * @return an integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
     *         text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
     *         otherwise
     */
    public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
}

private RectF mTextRect = new RectF();

private RectF mAvailableSpaceRect;

private SparseIntArray mTextCachedSizes;

private TextPaint mPaint;

private float mMaxTextSize;

private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

private float mMinTextSize = 20;

private int mWidthLimit;

private static final int NO_LINE_LIMIT = -1;
private int mMaxLines;

private boolean mEnableSizeCache = true;
private boolean mInitializedDimens;

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    mPaint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
    mMaxTextSize = getTextSize();
    mAvailableSpaceRect = new RectF();
    mTextCachedSizes = new SparseIntArray();
    if (mMaxLines == 0) {
        // no value was assigned during construction
        mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
    }
}

@Override
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    mMaxTextSize = size;
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize();
}

@Override
public void setMaxLines(int maxlines) {
    super.setMaxLines(maxlines);
    mMaxLines = maxlines;
    adjustTextSize();
}

public int getMaxLines() {
    return mMaxLines;
}

@Override
public void setSingleLine() {
    super.setSingleLine();
    mMaxLines = 1;
    adjustTextSize();
}

@Override
public void setSingleLine(boolean singleLine) {
    super.setSingleLine(singleLine);
    if (singleLine) {
        mMaxLines = 1;
    } else {
        mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
    }
    adjustTextSize();
}

@Override
public void setLines(int lines) {
    super.setLines(lines);
    mMaxLines = lines;
    adjustTextSize();
}

@Override
public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
    Context c = getContext();
    Resources r;

    if (c == null)
        r = Resources.getSystem();
    else
        r = c.getResources();
    mMaxTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size,
            r.getDisplayMetrics());
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize();
}

@Override
public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
    super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
    mSpacingMult = mult;
    mSpacingAdd = add;
}

/**
 * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
 * 
 * @param minTextSize
 */
public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize) {
    mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
    adjustTextSize();
}

private void adjustTextSize() {
    if (!mInitializedDimens) {
        return;
    }
    int startSize = (int) mMinTextSize;
    int heightLimit = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingBottom()
            - getCompoundPaddingTop();
    mWidthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft()
            - getCompoundPaddingRight();
    mAvailableSpaceRect.right = mWidthLimit;
    mAvailableSpaceRect.bottom = heightLimit;
    super.setTextSize(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
            efficientTextSizeSearch(startSize, (int) mMaxTextSize,
                    mSizeTester, mAvailableSpaceRect));
}

private final SizeTester mSizeTester = new SizeTester() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSPace) {
        mPaint.setTextSize(suggestedSize);
        String text = getText().toString();
        boolean singleline = getMaxLines() == 1;
        if (singleline) {
            mTextRect.bottom = mPaint.getFontSpacing();
            mTextRect.right = mPaint.measureText(text);
        } else {
            StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, mPaint,
                    mWidthLimit, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult,
                    mSpacingAdd, true);
            // return early if we have more lines
            if (getMaxLines() != NO_LINE_LIMIT
                    && layout.getLineCount() > getMaxLines()) {
                return 1;
            }
            mTextRect.bottom = layout.getHeight();
            int maxWidth = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
                if (maxWidth < layout.getLineWidth(i)) {
                    maxWidth = (int) layout.getLineWidth(i);
                }
            }
            mTextRect.right = maxWidth;
        }

        mTextRect.offsetTo(0, 0);
        if (availableSPace.contains(mTextRect)) {
            // may be too small, don't worry we will find the best match
            return -1;
        } else {
            // too big
            return 1;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Enables or disables size caching, enabling it will improve performance
 * where you are animating a value inside TextView. This stores the font
 * size against getText().length() Be careful though while enabling it as 0
 * takes more space than 1 on some fonts and so on.
 * 
 * @param enable
 *            enable font size caching
 */
public void enableSizeCache(boolean enable) {
    mEnableSizeCache = enable;
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

private int efficientTextSizeSearch(int start, int end,
        SizeTester sizeTester, RectF availableSpace) {
    if (!mEnableSizeCache) {
        return binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
    }
    int key = getText().toString().length();
    int size = mTextCachedSizes.get(key);
    if (size != 0) {
        return size;
    }
    size = binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
    mTextCachedSizes.put(key, size);
    return size;
}

private static int binarySearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester,
        RectF availableSpace) {
    int lastBest = start;
    int lo = start;
    int hi = end - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
        int midValCmp = sizeTester.onTestSize(mid, availableSpace);
        if (midValCmp < 0) {
            lastBest = lo;
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else if (midValCmp > 0) {
            hi = mid - 1;
            lastBest = hi;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    // make sure to return last best
    // this is what should always be returned
    return lastBest;

}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
        final int before, final int after) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
    adjustTextSize();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwidth,
        int oldheight) {
    mInitializedDimens = true;
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
    if (width != oldwidth || height != oldheight) {
        adjustTextSize();
    }
}
}
```

There is one library also available on github

https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Happy Coding!

Comment: if it helps, you can mark it as correct answer to help others as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Android has provides a view component named [Chips](https://material.google.com/components/chips.html#) that allows you to include text, image, icon etc. You may try to combine chips with staggeredGrid to achieve view as above. Or, you may try using [ChipView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2580) as it is highly customizable. To use your own layout, you need to create an adapter and implements `ChipViewAdapter`. Head on ChipView for more detail. - https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView

```
public class MainChipViewAdapter extends ChipViewAdapter {
public MainChipViewAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public int getLayoutRes(int position) {
    Tag tag = (Tag) getChip(position);

    switch (tag.getType()) {
        default:
        case 2:
        case 4:
            return 0;

        case 1:
        case 5:
            return R.layout.chip_double_close;

        case 3:
            return R.layout.chip_close;
    }
}
```